# Не показывает предварительный просмотр макета в activity_main_drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-drawer

Ребят помогите как исправить правильное отображение, некоторые говорят что не хватает пакетов каких-то, строго не судите, просто только начал разбираться.[image]

Comment: Покажите текст xml. Судя по все там какие-то проблемы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Один из возможных вариантов решение - установить режим редактирования разметки на `Text` и дальше там можно включить отображение дизайна (preview):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше вы можете поменять режим отображения этой вкладки например как плавающее окно и можно его переместить как вам будет удобно. Вот [статья](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117740/android-studio-design-view-too-small) где написано как и что нужно сделать. И вот [статья](https://www.quora.com/Design-view-is-not-getting-displayed-in-my-Android-Studio-What-should-I-do) где возможно так же есть другой вариант решения данной проблемы.