# Разметка | Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть ли возможность смотреть разметку страницы прямо во время её отрисовки? Как в html. Например, я хочу посмотреть, как именно добавляется мой элемент (пусть будет TextView) на Layout (его разметку). Надеюсь, что вы поняли меня.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не показывает предварительный просмотр макета в activity\_main\_drawer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065838/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-activity-main-drawer)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor

Answer (score 1):

Смотреть страницу в реалтайме возможности нет.

Вы можете воспользоваться предварительным просмотром макета. Если же вы хотите просмотреть разметку запущенного приложения вы можете воспользоваться [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector):

> Tools -> LayoutInspector

Либо [UiAuthomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing):

`$ uiautomatorviewer` - из консоли